# Extracting values from a matrix based on values from another matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, search, 3d, location

I have two matrices in MATLAB. One is a 1543x3 matrix where the first column contains an x position, the second column contains the corresponding y position and the third column contains the corresponding z position. The second matrix is a 3D 256x256x36 matrix containing values. I want to extract all values in the second matrix that occur at positions listed in the first matrix.

Currently, my method is to look through every single position in the 256x256x36 using for loops and compare each position to every position in the 1543x3 matrix. This method works, but is taking an extremely long time and I have about 24 sets of data like this to process.

Does anyone have an idea how I could improve the efficiency of this?

Comment: Please post your current code, since it is not exactly clear what you’re doing. Posting code makes things explicit and is also easier to talk about.

Comment: Does your first matrix contain indices into the second matrix? If so, did you see the `sub2ind` function?

Comment: Suppose `A` is your 1543x3 matrix of indices, `B` is your 256x256x36 matrix of values, and `B` is indexed as in `B(ix, iy, iz)`. Then `sub2ind` as suggested by Cris works as follows: `A(sub2ind(size(A), B(:,1), B(:,2), B(:,3)))'